# remote logging using syslogd - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS - just will not send

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, syslogd

so, playing with centralized logging and i just cannot get syslogd to send the messages to a remote syslog server.

background:

**syslog server** is setup and working, tested with other devices sending logs into it.

**networking** both server and client reside in the same subnet, firewalls are off on server, from what i can tell ubuntu has no firewall configured. tested 514 open on the server from the client and get a successful connection.

**setup/test process**

syslogd didn't seem to exist on my install, so i installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install -y inetutils-syslogd
```

modified the config file in /etc/syslogd.conf to include 2 lines:

```
*.* /home/lee/test
*.* @10.120.1.20
```

saved and reloaded syslogd by sending the hangup signal

```
killall -s SIGHUP syslogd
```

testing with the logger function:

```
logger "test"
```

inserts lines into the local file, but **nothing** gets to the server.

tried setting up a tcpdump on 512 outbound to see if anything is going through:

```
tcpdump -n -s 1500 -X port 514 -w /home/lee/tcpdump.pcap
```

the file is empty, tried tracing the PID as such:

```
strace -s 500 -tfp 188341 -o /home/lee/strace_syslog
```

the output of the file indicates it sees the test messages, and writes to some outputs, but nothing seems to indicate writing out to the remote syslog address...

```
1446  10:27:52 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>) = 1
1446  10:28:03 recvfrom(21, "<13>May 18 10:28:03 lee: test", 1024, 0, 0x7ffd918070e0, [110->0]) = 29
1446  10:28:03 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP ALRM], [], 8) = 0
1446  10:28:03 writev(22, [{iov_base="May 18 10:28:03", iov_len=15}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="ubuntu-docker", iov_len=13}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="lee: test", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 6) = 40
1446  10:28:03 writev(20, [{iov_base="May 18 10:28:03", iov_len=15}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="ubuntu-docker", iov_len=13}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="lee: test", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 6) = 40
1446  10:28:03 writev(11, [{iov_base="May 18 10:28:03", iov_len=15}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="ubuntu-docker", iov_len=13}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="lee: test", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 6) = 40
1446  10:28:03 writev(6, [{iov_base="May 18 10:28:03", iov_len=15}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="ubuntu-docker", iov_len=13}, {iov_base=" ", iov_len=1}, {iov_base="lee: test", iov_len=9}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 6) = 40
1446  10:28:03 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
1446  10:28:03 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=21, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, -1) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
1446  10:28:10 --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
1446  10:28:10 alarm(30)                = 0
1446  10:28:10 rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})  = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
1446  10:28:10 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=21, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 2, -1) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
1446  10:28:40 --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
1446  10:28:40 alarm(30)                = 0
1446  10:28:40 rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})  = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
```

what have i missed???

i just cannot get it to output to a remote host.... **from my testing i am confident that it is a configuration issue in /etc/syslogd.conf but i cannot see what!**

Comment: Your confidence may be misplaced!  Your syslogd may consider this message as coming from another system.  Syslogd does not, by default, forward messages.

Comment: A. you shouldn't have install `inetutils-syslogd` - Ubuntu comes with RSyslog which is a much better implementation. I have used RSyslog successfully for remote logging many times and it is recommended.

Comment: B. While `logger` by default sends messages through `/dev/log`, because of your non-standard setup it may fail to do so and fallback to logging over UDP - in that case, rsyslog will refuse to forward the message as noted by @GerardH.Pille

Comment: o ok! thank you guys, so the correct way to proceed would be to now uninstall inetutils-syslogd hopefully reverting back to now use rsyslogd instead?

Comment: uninstalled  ```inetutils-syslogd```. then unmasked rsyslog. added this line to the rsyslog.conf file:
```*.* @@10.120.1.20:1468```
restarted rsyslogd ```sudo service rsyslog restart``` 

testing with Logger but i still don't get any messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force your local syslogd to forward messages, restart it with

```
-h, --hop
    Enable forwarding remote messages. By default syslogd will not forward
    messages it receives from remote hosts.
```

Comment: this was extremely helpful and i am very surprised that it is not more results from my goggle searches :) i should have ready the man page more thoroughly! thank you.

Comment: I assure you it took quite some digging before I understood what could be wrong with your configuration - since nothing was wrong.  ;-)